# How to secure dynamically created and named "directories" per user inside an Aws S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

i’m looking for help on how to how to secure dynamically created and named "directories" per user inside an Aws S3 bucket. I looked a lot of AWS S3 and IAM documentation but i’m not able to find the « best » way to implement what i want without reaching aws limits too fast... Note : I need to use AWS S3 only to store files and have entity datas coming from my database (like users and books uuids, see below).

Let me explain :

**What i have :**

- My own database storing users and books datas like v4 uuid for both entities and some more other datas useless for aws.
- Dynamically created AWS IAM programmatic users named with generated v4 uuids.
- An S3 Bucket containing « directories » (i know there is no « directories »in s3) named with generated v4 uuids inside a « books » directory.
  Unfortunatelly i don’t want to create a structure depending on the user uuid v4 because multiple users could be able to work on a book.

Bucket Structure example :

```
-My Bucket/
    - Books/
        - d32c04f7-bbd3-4331-b53d-2528d783c0ef/
            - anotherDirectory/
                - object.txt
                - etc...
        - d32c04f7-bbd3-4331-b53d-2528d783c0ef/
            - ...
        - e10513c2-2464-4d7b-a4b3-2177886325b7/
- etc.
```

**What i want :**

Deny access to all books by default and allow access to users per «books» (by attaching them iam policies or with a bucket policy, what will be the most relevant to my case), with the constraints that maybe multiple users can read or write file inside a book directory depending on their « authorizations ».

**What i ended up with :**

I thought of adding Aws Tags to users with keys containing Books uuid with the users’ status inside this book as the value. *Exemple (Tag Key/Value): d32c04f7-bbd3-4331-b53d-2528d783c0ef / author.*
    I don’t know if it’s the most relevant solution but with that i can’t manage to create a strategy that check for users’s keys matching the s3 object keys (book uuid) before trying to access objects inside it…

Could you please help me with that or maybe give me a more relevant approach to my case ? If you require more precisions on this case, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want to do this with IAM only or using some sort of database and your own logic?

Comment: Hello, i'm using AWS S3 only to store files and have coming infos from my database (like user and books uuids for instances)